# CrystalReportsViewer prompts for password but doesn't accept it

Tags: crystal-reports

I am trying to use a CrystalReportViewer control to display a report in a Visual Studio 2012 project.  I am providing all information required to connect to the database, including server name, port number, database name, user name and password.  When I run the program below, the control shows me a dialog that includes the correct connection string, database name and user, and prompts me for a password, even though I already gave it one.  When I give it the correct password, a pop-up appears saying "Log-in failed.  Try again."  What am I doing wrong?

By the way, there are no subreports in this report.  When I ran the program below, I put a breakpoint in the code that processes subreports, and it was never hit.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

using CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine;
using CrystalDecisions.Shared;
using CrystalDecisions.Windows.Forms;

namespace Example
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private string _serverName;
        private string _databaseName;
        private string _user;
        private string _passwd;
        private ReportDocument _report;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void crystalReportViewer1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string reportFile = "C:\\Users\\rdrichardson\\OneDrive - Rad-Con\\CAPS Builds\\trunk\\Debug Crawfordsville\\Reports\\English\\allbases_no_subreports.rpt";
            _report = new ReportDocument();            
            _report.Load(reportFile);

            _serverName = "Provider=Provider=PostgreSQL OLE DB Provider;Data Source=localhost;Port=5432timeout=1000;";
            // _serverName = "Driver={PostgreSQL};Server=IP address;Port=5432;Database=Algoma;Uid=caps;Pwd=asdlkjqp;";
            // _serverName = "Driver={PostgreSQL};Server=IP address;Port=5432;";
            _databaseName = "Algoma";
            _user = "caps";
            _passwd = "asdlkjqp";

            LogOnToTables();

            crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = _report;
        }
        private void LogOnToTables()
        {
            string location;
            ReportObjects crReportObjects;
            SubreportObject crSubreportObject;
            ReportDocument crSubreportDocument;
            Database crDatabase;
            Tables crTables;
            TableLogOnInfo crTableLogOnInfo;

            ConnectionInfo crConnectInfo = new ConnectionInfo();

            if (_report == null) return;


            // Setup the ODBC/ADO connect string
            crConnectInfo.DatabaseName = _databaseName;
            crConnectInfo.ServerName = _serverName;
            crConnectInfo.Type = ConnectionInfoType.CRQE;
            crConnectInfo.UserID = _user;
            crConnectInfo.Password = _passwd;

            _report.SetDatabaseLogon(_user, _passwd);
            _report.DataSourceConnections.Clear();

            crDatabase = _report.Database;
            crTables = crDatabase.Tables;

            //loop through all the tables and pass in the connection info
            foreach (Table crTable in crTables)
            {
                location = crTable.Location;
                crTableLogOnInfo = crTable.LogOnInfo;
                crTableLogOnInfo.ConnectionInfo = crConnectInfo;
                // crTable.LogOnInfo.ConnectionInfo.DatabaseName = string.Empty;
                crTable.ApplyLogOnInfo(crTableLogOnInfo);
            }

            //set the crSections object to the current report's sections
            Sections crSections = _report.ReportDefinition.Sections;

            //loop through all the sections to find all the report objects
            foreach (Section crSection in crSections)
            {
                crReportObjects = crSection.ReportObjects;
                //loop through all the report objects to find all the subreports
                foreach (CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportObject crReportObject in crReportObjects)
                {
                    if (crReportObject.Kind == ReportObjectKind.SubreportObject)
                    {
                        //you will need to typecast the reportobject to a subreport 
                        //object once you find it
                        crSubreportObject = (SubreportObject)crReportObject;

                        //open the subreport object
                        crSubreportDocument = crSubreportObject.OpenSubreport(crSubreportObject.SubreportName);

                        //set the database and tables objects to work with the subreport
                        crDatabase = crSubreportDocument.Database;
                        crTables = crDatabase.Tables;

                        //loop through all the tables in the subreport and 
                        //set up the connection info and apply it to the tables
                        foreach (Table crTable in crTables)
                        {
                            location = crTable.Location;
                            crTableLogOnInfo = crTable.LogOnInfo;
                            crTableLogOnInfo.ConnectionInfo = crConnectInfo;
                            crTable.ApplyLogOnInfo(crTableLogOnInfo);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: Have you tried this code with a new/simple/empty report?

Comment: It is a simple report.  It has no subreports (verified by putting a breakpoint in the code that processes subreports and seeing that it does not get hit).

Comment: I suggest to give a new report a try. Maybe your report is "broken". If a new report works then it has to be something else.

Answer (score 0):

```
_user = "caps";
_passwd = "asdlkjqp";
```

This value is hardcoded, Irrespective of your input, it will always take this password. Try giving actual user / password instead of `asdlkjqp`

Comment: Thank you, but you misunderstand the problem.  "caps" and "asdlkjqp" are valid user names and passwords.  Crystal Reports should not be asking me for another password.  And even if it does, and I re-enter "asklkjqp", it should accept it instead of saying "Login failed".